# How to place element over the float image?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

I need to place zoom icons over my blog images.

Easy for simple images (I'm using jQuery to add <span> element):

`<a href="..." rel="lightbox">
<span style="position:absolute; background-image: url(zoom.png);"/>
<img src="img.jpg" />
</a>`

But some images have "float:left" or "float:right" alignment. How can I place <span> over the float images?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Nvbe/1/

Comment: Is the anchor part of the 'original', unmodified HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your HTML structure, is there a particular reason you are using a span? A div seems to be doing the trick just fine.

There's a working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/4Nvbe/ but if you tried altering it to add a div instead so the markup looks like:

```
<a href="..." rel="lightbox"><div style="position:absolute; background-image: url(zoom.png);"/><img src="img.jpg" /></a>
```

it might solve your problems.

In my example I've also just used a class, that way the styling/visual control is left with the stylesheet rather than bleeding in to your JS.

Comment: Yes, I have no div, it's just a common blog structure, float images is for text wrap. My update: http://jsfiddle.net/4Nvbe/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, but it will depend heavily on the rest of your styles.

I've placed position: relative and moved the floats to the anchor (the rest of your code may prevent you from doing this I admit. See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am_d/TQabN) to see it in action.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    img {width:30px;height:30px;border:1px solid red;display:block;margin:3px;}
    span {width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid blue;display:block;margin:3px;}
    a { border:2px dotted green;display:inline-block;position:relative; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
<a href="#" rel="lightbox"> <span style="position:absolute; background-image: url(zoom.png);"></span><img src="img.jpg" /> </a>
   <a href="#" rel="lightbox"> <span style="position:absolute; background-image: url(zoom.png);"></span><img src="img.jpg" /> </a><br style="clear:both" />
<a href="#" rel="lightbox"> <span style="position:absolute; background-image: url(zoom.png);"></span><img style="float:right;"  src="img.jpg" /> </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. I can't use it, your code is just stopping text wrap, same as removing float at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem and used a `<div>` instead of `<span>` like Pete Uh has suggested, and it works.